# How to add Get in Touch page in webpage?

Tags: javascript, css

I have developed a webpage using html, css and Javascript. Now i like to add 'get in touch' page in it so that visitor can send me a message on the website. How can i go ahead with this? Do i need to establish a database for this?

Comment: Your question is vague, can you please elaborate

Comment: I just want to add a page where visitor can send me a message on the website. @Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form?

Like this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```
<form>
First name:
<input type="text">
Last name:
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this is exactly i want. One thing i am not sure about, where does this info stores? How can i access this info? @jared

Comment: You will need to write server side language for that